# Смена языка при помощи select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Изначально делал по клику на кнопки (все работает нормально), а по select не срабатывает. Как исправить для select?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.rus').on('click', function() {
      var r = $('.localization').each(function() {
         var el = $(this);
         var key = (el.attr('caption'));
         el.text(rus[key]);
      });
   });

   $('.eng').on('click', function() {
      var r = $('.localization').each(function() {
         var el = $(this);
         var key = (el.attr('caption'));
         el.text(eng[key]);
      });
   });
   
   var rus = {
      test: 'тест',
      name: 'имя',

   };
   var eng = {
      test: 'test',
      name: 'name',
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='localization' caption='test'>тест</span>
<span class='localization' caption='name'>имя</span>
<br>

<input class='rus' type=button value='rus'>
<input class='eng' type=button value='eng'><br><br>

<select class="#select_language">
    <option>Выберите язык</option>
    <option class='rus' value="rus">Русский</option>
    <option class='eng' value="eng">Английский</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Следить за изменением значения select-a можно с помощью обработчика события `change` select-a, определяя что выбрано по его `.value`:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var languageData = this.value == "rus" ? rus : eng;
  $(".localization").text(function() {
    var caption = $(this).attr("caption");
    return languageData[caption];
  });
});

var rus = {
  test: 'тест',
  name: 'имя',

};
var eng = {
  test: 'test',
  name: 'name',
};
```

```html
<span class='localization' caption='test'>тест</span>
<span class='localization' caption='name'>имя</span>
<br>
<select class="#select_language">
    <option>Выберите язык</option>
    <option class='rus' value="rus">Русский</option>
    <option class='eng' value="eng">Английский</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Ещё заменил `$(".localization").each` на `$(".localization").text` - так несколько короче

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.rus').on('click', function() {
      changeLang($(this).val());
   });


   $('.eng').on('click', function() {
      changeLang($(this).val());
   });
   
   $('.select_language').on("change", function(e){
      changeLang($(this).val());
   });
   
   
  function changeLang(lang){
    $('.localization').each(function() {
      var el = $(this),
         key = (el.attr('caption'));

      if(languages[lang]){
       el.text(languages[lang][key]);
      }
    });
  }
   

  var languages = {
    rus : {
        test: 'тест',
        name: 'имя',

     },
     eng : {
        test: 'test',
        name: 'name',
     }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='localization' caption='test'>тест</span>
<span class='localization' caption='name'>имя</span>
<br>

<input class='rus' type=button value='rus'>
<input class='eng' type=button value='eng'><br><br>

<select class="select_language">
    <option>Выберите язык</option>
    <option class='rus' value="rus">Русский</option>
    <option class='eng' value="eng">Английский</option>
</select>
```

Изменение я вывел в отдельную функцию, так меньше кода получается)

Comment: @Regent Спасибо. В пример сделал как у Вас. Удобно однако. На будущее учту, что так можно)

Comment: На здоровье. Единственное что меня огорчает - это строка `lang = lang == 'rus' ? rus: eng;`. Тут две проблемы: 1. Меняется значение входного параметра. 2. Меняется тип переменной `lang` (JS это разрешает, но лучше от этого не становится). Было бы здорово поменять на `var что-то = lang == ...`

Comment: @Regent а чем это чревато?

Comment: @Regent создав один массив с языками, мы устраним проблему с `lang = lang == 'rus' ? rus: eng;`, теперь можно увеличивать количество языков, без каких либо сложностей

Comment: И то, и другое - лишь правила хорошего тона, так что чревато это может быть только усложнением чтения кода и возникновении логических ошибок в коде. Например, без этого придётся проверять всё тело метода на предмет изменений входного параметра или можно благополучно забыть, что он поменялся, и попытаться где-то в нижней части метода использовать параметр как будто он имеет первоначальное значение

Comment: @Regent Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Да, безусловно создание объекта (у вас `languages` - это всё-таки объект, а не массив) позволяет легко добавлять новые языки, и это хорошее решение. Просто в данном случае всего два языка, поэтому я не стал заморачиваться за это. Ну и плюсом в таком решении нужно обрабатывать значения-ключи, которых нет в объекте. Если у вас сейчас выбрать "Выберите язык", то код упадёт с ошибкой

Comment: @Regent это да. улучшать код можно бесконечно)

Comment: Подскажите из этой же задачи что я писал. Допустим в варианте перевода часть текста жирным выделяется:
var rus = {
      test: ' <b>текст жирным</b> тест',
      name: 'имя',
   };
Как сделать чтобы тег <b> в переводе прочитался именно как тег а не текст при отображении информации на сайте?

Comment: @predel2007 делайте это через css. Т.е допустим к `span` который отвечает за текст добавьте еще класс допустим `bold` в css, опишите данный селектор нужными свойствами например `.bold {font-weight:bold}` и тогда у вас всегда будет данный текст жирным)

Comment: я думал разбивать поблочно, но это надо все править, а если кусок кода такой: <div class='localization' caption='material_5'><b>Щепа древесная</b> Код ТН ВЭД 4401</div>
То с заменой содержимого проблема. Я думал что может как-то тег можно экранировать чтоли чтобы при отображении он как тег и прочитался.

Comment: @predel2007 тогда, за место `el.text(languages[lang][key]);` пишите `el.html(languages[lang][key]);` и тогда можно будет использовать html теги

Comment: При смене языков из-за разного количество символов немного местами подплывает верстка, - можно ли как-то подтягивать разные файлы стилей при подключении соответствующего языка? Как это можно в этом коде прописать?

Comment: @predel2007 [ссылка](https://web.izjum.com/javascrip-css-files) можете посмотреть тут, как это делается. Но допустим у вас будет больше 2 языков, вы на каждый язык будете делать свой css файл. Вам потом будет сложно редактировать верстку.