# В переключении языка менять название языка

Tags: javascript

Есть меню, состоящее из 3 языков. и есть div где показан выбранный язык. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на другой язык менялось содержимое div?

```
<div class="small-nav-items">
    <div id="lang" class="round">Ru</div>
        <ul class="lang" id="lang-list">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="round">Ru</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="round">Uk</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="round">En</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


</div>
```

До значения языка я добралась

```
var arrLang = document.querySelectorAll('ul.lang>li>a'),
i;
for (i = 0; i < arrLang.length; i++) {
console.log(arrLang[i].innerText)
}
```

но как это дальше применить?

Comment: `jquery` не используете?

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893696/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-select/893709#893709) Подобный вопрос уже поднимался

Comment: @Grundy, там вопрос то jquery  и select, тут про js и ссылки. Для начинающего будет сложно это считать дубликатом и переделать код. зря имхо закрыл.

Comment: @teran, ок, напишешь ответ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// box - это тот div#lang, куда нужно запихнуть новое значение языка
var box = document.querySelector("#lang");

// получаем <ul> список .lang и навешиваем на него слушатель клика.
// На него, а не на каждого из его потомков потому, что так лаконичнее код и выше производительность.
document.querySelector(".lang").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  
  // Отключаем переход по ссылке (стандартное поведение)
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Поскольку обработчик у нас навешен на <ul>, то клик мог произвойти как по одной из ссылок, так и за ее пределами.
  // Поэтому убеждаемся, что пользователь кликнул именно по ссылке
  if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
  
    // Меняем значение div#lang соответствующим образом
    box.textContent = event.target.textContent;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="small-nav-items">
  <div id="lang" class="round">Ru</div>
  <ul class="lang" id="lang-list">
      <li>
          <a href="#" class="round">Ru</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#" class="round">Uk</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#" class="round">En</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```